# ВК API SDK android “sdk_fingerprint is incorrect”

Tags: java, android

Для авторизаций в приложений использую VK API, в debug версий проблем нет,после публикаций в play market пишет  “sdk_fingerprint is incorrect”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас возникает проблема с отпечатком сертификата. Для debug версии такой ключ не особо важен и он генерируется сразу же при установке Android manager. Как только вы отправляйте ваш проект в release, то нужно уже генерировать отпечаток сертификата с помощью утилиты [keytool](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/221-urok-123-kak-podpisat-prilozhenie-utility-keytool-i-jarsigner.html), хотелось бы отметить, что такой же ключ вы отправляете в play market, когда публикуете приложение так что ключи на vk.com и в play market совпадают. Перепроверьте ваш проект и протестируйте вновь.

P.S. некоторые IDE, как например IntelliJ от JetBrains, позволяют генерировать отпечаток внутри проекта.

Answer (score 2):

Поздний ответ, но кому-то сэкономлю кучу времени: консоль google play -> управление релизом -> подписи приложений.